# Cases for weak field approximation for EFEs being applied to non-weak fields

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory

Consider the Einstein Field Equations $$G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}.$$ These equations are a set of 10 independent highly coupled non linear hyperbolic-elliptic second order PDEs. This implies that they are extremely hard to solve, hence the need for approximation methods. The weak field approximation for the EFEs is simply an application of Perturbation Theory on GR. In the weak field approximation we take the metric tensor $$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu},$$ where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, using the (-,+,+,+) metric signiture is given by $$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1),$$ which is just the regular Minkowski metric tensor. Furthermore, $h_{\mu\nu}$ is just a small perturbation added on to Minkowski metric such that it satisfies the condition $$|h_{\mu\nu}| \ll 1.$$ Furthermore, consider a metric $\mathrm{d}s^2$ where there is a strong gravitational field and an exact solution is possible. If we know there exists an exact solution for the particular metric, can we still apply the weak field approximation and assume that the strong field is weak despite the field being strong? I would assume so since it is an approximation but I just need some clarification on this topic.

Comment: Perturbations can't deviate too much from Minkowski metric, so you can't approximate an arbitrary metric as a perturbation on Minkowski background. Ex: think about Schwarzschild metric

Comment: can we assume $x=0.001$ despite it being $=1000$?

Comment: Are you interested in the weak-field approximation or in something more general? As the words suggest, if the field is strong, it is not weak. However, one can still use perturbation theory in GR without picking the Minkowski metric as a background (perturbations in Schwarzschild, for example). Is this what you're aiming for or are you interested in the actual weak field approximation?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves That is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: @aygx I suggest rephrasing the question in terms of whether perturbation theory can be applied for backgrounds that are not flat (in short, yes). In the way it is currently written, it is a bit hard to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Einstein's field equations (EFE) can be developed in Post-Newton expansion, an expansion in a small parameter which is typically the speed of motion of masses in the given gravitational field normalized on the speed of light: $v/c$ or even $(v/c)^2$ and higher orders of it.
Of course one has to make sure that $(v/c)^2$ is sufficiently small, otherwise the EFEs have to be solved directly. But the Post-Newton expansion makes GR treatable. Einstein, for instance, computed Mercury's precession in Post-Newton expansion. A decomposition $g_{\mu\nu} \approx \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ is applied in Post-Newton expansion.

Have a look on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion

Answer (score 0):

> … can we still apply the weak field approximation and assume that the strong field is weak despite the field being strong?

This sounds like an oxymoron, but one possible interpretation  is when a solution of linearized Einstein equations solves the full nonlinear EFEs.

For example, here is the theorem proven by Xanthopoulos [1]:

> If $(M,g_{ab})$ is an exact vacuum solution of Einstein’s equation, $l_a$ a null vector field and if $l_a l_b$ satisfies the linearized equation on background $(M,g_{ab})$, then $g_{ab}+l_al_b$ is an exact vacuum solution.

These solutions are of *Kerr–Schild type*. Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics are examples of this class with the Minkowski background.

1. Xanthopoulos, B. C. (1978). *Exact vacuum solutions of Einstein’s equation from linearized solutions*, Journal of Mathematical Physics, 19(7), 1607-1609, [doi:10.1063/1.523851](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.523851).